# Finite free resolution of a finitely generated $\mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, polynomial-rings, syzygies

Let $R=\mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Say $M = \text{im}\, \varphi$, where the homomorphism $\varphi:R^k \rightarrow R^l$ is given by an $l\times k$ matrix $A$ with elements in $R$. So $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. I am interested in the length of a minimal free resolution of $M$.

Here's what I thought might work. Say $R' = \mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and $M'= \text{im}\, \varphi'$, where the homomorphism $\varphi':R'^k \rightarrow R'^l$ is given by the same matrix $A$ as above (i.e., all the entries of $A$ are polynomials with integer coefficients). By the Hilbert's syzygy theorem, a minimal free resolution of $M'$ is of length at most $n$. Let $A_i$, for $i=0,\ldots,n$, be the matrices associated with the maps $\varphi'_i$ in the minimal free resolution of $M'$, with $A_0 = A$ and $\varphi'_0 = \varphi'$.

Here are my questions:

1. Are the entries of $A_i$ also polynomials with *integer* coefficients for all $i$? I think, if they are not integers, we can scale them appropriately to make them integers.
2. Can we use the matrices $A_i$ (with integer coefficients) to construct a minimal free resolution of $M$? It seems to make sense intuitively, and it seems to be true in several examples I have worked out on Macaulay2.
3. If the answer to question 2 is "no" in general, is there a characterisation of $A$ for which the answer is "yes"?

Since $\mathbb Z$ has global (homological) dimension $1$, $R$ has global dimension $n+1$. However, this is projective dimension, and I am not sure if a projective resolution is the same as a free resolution for $R$-modules. Moreover, $n+1>n$, where $n$ is the global dimension of $R'$. So it is possible that the above procedure might be wrong. If so, I would like to know where it goes wrong.

**Update 1:**

As an example, consider $n=0$. Then, $M$ is a free $\mathbb Z$-module because any submodule of a free $\mathbb Z$-module is free. Therefore, the free resolution of $M$ has length $0$. Of course, this is not true if $M$ has torsion (which is why global dimension of $\mathbb Z$ is $1$ instead of $0$). So I think the above procedure implies that whenever $M$ is the image of a homomorphism between free $R$-modules of finite rank, its minimal free resolution is of length at most $n$.

**Update 2:**

There are some trivial counterexamples when the matrix $A$ is such that its columns do not form a minimal generating set of $M$. For example, consider $n=1$, i.e., $R=\mathbb Z[x]$, and the $1\times 2$ matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} x &1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $\ker A$ is generated by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -x \end{pmatrix}$, which means the length of the free resolution is $1$. However, the module $M$ is free because $\text{im}\,A \cong R$, so the length of its minimal free resolution is $0$. So, I am adding the assumption that the columns of $A$ form a minimal generating set of $M$.

**Update 3:**

There are matrices $A$ such that the columns of $A$ form a minimal generating set of $M$ but not of $M'$. For example, the columns of $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & x \end{pmatrix}$ form a minimal generating set of $M$ but not of $M'$. Consequently, the minimal free resolutions of $M$ and $M'$ do not have the same length. So, I am modifying the assumption to the following stronger version: the columns of $A$ form a minimal generating set of $M'$. It follows that they form a minimal generating set of $M$ as well.

**Update 4:**

First, the answer to question 1 is clearly *yes* because this won't affect the free resolution of $M'$.

After the discussion in comments below, I see that the notion of minimal free resolution in my question is not standard. So let me define what I mean by a minimal free resolution: *it is a free resolution with minimal length*. By the syzygy theorems for $R$ (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.08117.pdf)) and $R'$ (Hilbert's syzygy theorem), both $M$ and $M'$ have finite lengths, so this notion gives a finite answer. With this definition, question 2 can be restated as follows:

2. Given a minimal free resolution of $M'$ with matrices $A_i$ chosen so that they have only integer coefficients, can the same matrices be used to construct a free resolution of $M$? (Note that, now, I don't require the latter to be a minimal free resolution.)

I think question 2 then boils down to the following:

2. Say $A_1$ is a matrix of polynomials with integer coefficients such that $\text{im}\,A_1 = \ker A$ over $R'$. Then, does $A_1$ satisfy $\text{im}\,A_1 = \ker A$ over $R$? If this is true for $A_1$, then by induction, all $A_i$ satisfy $\text{im}\,A_{i+1} = \ker A_i$ over both $R'$ and $R$, as long as we choose $A_i$ such that its columns form a minimal generating set with least cardinality of $\text{im}\,A_i = \ker A_{i-1}$ over $R'$.

Let me give an example of what I mean by this. Consider $n=2$, and $A = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix}$. Then, in a minimal free resolution of $M'$, we have $A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} y\\ -x\end{pmatrix}$ and $A_2 = 0$. Now, $\text{im}\,A_1 = \ker A$ and $\text{im}\,A_2 = \ker A_1$ over both $R'$ and $R$. Therefore, $A_1$ and $A_2$ give a (probably minimal) free resolution of $M$ as well.

Comment: I have largely undeveloped intuition, so I may be totally wrong. But a concern comes from the following parallel of group rings/algebras of finite cyclic groups. $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^n-1)$ is the group algebra of the group $C_n$. Its modules split by Maschke's theorem, so projective resolutions are short. On the other hand, the corresponding integer group ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^n-1)$ has [periodically repeating (co)homology](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_cohomology_of_finite_cyclic_groups). Whatever understanding I ever had is now heavily cobwebbed, so ... :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for that example! I still feel what I said might work for the kind of modules I mentioned in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by a minimal free resolution? I know this notion for local rings, but this is not the case here.

Comment: @user26857 I mean minimal in the sense described in the Wikipedia page on [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(algebra)): _Among these graded free resolutions, the minimal free resolutions are those for which the number of basis elements of each $E_i$ is minimal. The number of basis elements of each $E_i$ and their degrees are the same for all the minimal free resolutions of a graded module_. I should add that any finitely generated $\mathbb Z[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$-module has a free resolution of length at most $n+1$ as shown in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.08117.pdf).

Comment: @user26857 I assumed that a minimal free resolution is equivalently a free resolution with least possible length. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: As you can see there is no such notion in general. The one about graded modules doesn't apply here, so your quote from Wiki is not appropriate.

Comment: But if I understand well, a minimal free resolution is for you a free resolution of minimal length.

Comment: @user26857 Is the notion of minimal free resolution (in the usual sense) well-defined for $M'$ which is a $\mathbb Q[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$-module? If yes, then my question can be stated as follows: Given a minimal free resolution of $M'$ generated by the columns of $A$, can we use the $A_i$'s of that complex (appropriately chosen so that all coefficients are integers) to get a free resolution of $M$.

Comment: Quick check: I didn’t see the result mentioned, but can’t one use Quillen-Suslin to conclude? (Theorem 13 in https://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/the-quillen-suslin-theorem/ ) By usual regularity stuff $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow R^l \rightarrow \mathrm{coker}\varphi \rightarrow 0$ is exact, so can be extended into a finite projective resolution of $K=\mathrm{coker}\,\varphi$ with length $n+1$, ie something of length $n$ for $M$?

Comment: @Mindlack That's right but what I want is something stronger. If you apply the same argument to $R'$, you get the length of $M'$ to be $n-1$. I want $M$ to also have the same length. More generally, I want the resolutions to have same length over both $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$. If you are interested, [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/419947/149337) and [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/420098/149337) on math overflow are related and more precise.

Comment: Okay – but any $R$-module can be written as $\mathrm{coker}\,\varphi$, so it is possible that the $\mathrm{coker}\,\varphi$ to have projective dimension $n+1$, and thus $M$ must have projective dimension at least $n$ (whereas indeed $M’$ has projective dimension at most $n-1$). No?

Comment: @Mindlack That's right, it is not generally the case that $M$ and $M'$ have the same length. But as the examples above and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/419947/149337) suggest, there are cases when $M$ and $M'$ do have same length. In fact, the matrices in their resolutions are exactly the same. I want a characterization of $M$ for which this happens.

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @Mindlack You're welcome. I just wanted to add one thing. Given a resolution of $M$, I can get a resolution of $M'$ by tensoring it with $R'$. I want to know when the converse works, i.e., given a resolution of $M'$, by scaling the matrices of resolution to make all coefficients integers, can we get a resolution of an appropriately defined $M$? (How this $M$ is defined is what I describe [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/420098/149337).)